# Cs50 Pset4: Adieu - check50 gives error, but my results are correct

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, cs50

So my task is to ask users for names until they press control-d and then output in the format `Adieu, adieu, to Liesl, Friedrich, and Louisa` where Liesl, Friedrich and Louisa are names input by the  user. In my terminal, the results are correct no matter how many names I input, they output correctly, but check50 show a frown. Here's my code:

```
names = []

while True:
    try:
        #ask for input
        name = input("Name: ")
        #put in the list
        names.append(name)
    except (EOFError, ValueError):
        print()
        break

print("Adieu, adieu, to", end=" ")
#from first to second last, output names by comma
x = int(len(names)-2)
for amount in range(x):
    print(names[amount] , "," , end=" ", sep="")

#use 'and' to output last name
names.reverse()
#if two names in list
try:
      print(str(names[1]), end=" ")
      print("and", str(names[0]))
#if one name in list
except (ValueError, EOFError, IndexError):
    print(str(names[0]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the check50 link to read the detailed error message, and/or re-read the instructions. Your solution doesn't match the expected output when there are 3 or more names.

Expected ouptut when there are 3 or more names:

```
Adieu, adieu, to Liesl, Friedrich, and Louisa
Adieu, adieu, to Liesl, Friedrich, Louisa, and Kurt
```

Your program outputs (compare commas):

```
Adieu, adieu, to Liesl, Friedrich and Louisa
Adieu, adieu, to Liesl, Friedrich, Louisa and Kurt
```

Also, did you read the Hint about the `inflect` module? While not required, it will be very helpful in another pset.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use join method in question like this where you have to insert something in between..

Like for example

```
        result = " and ".join(names)
```

something like this depending on cases